# Support library missing

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to add an existing project as a module. However, it wont compile as it says this library is missing:

```
android-support-v4.jar => com.android.support:support-v4:20.+
```

I have opened the sdk manager and installed the latest version of Android Support Library but the error remains. How can I fix this please?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have the "Android Support Repository" installed under "Extras" in the SDK manager.

The support libraries are managed in a local Maven repository, and that repository is the "Android Support Repository" component.

Comment: I do have the latest version of Android Support Repository installed

Comment: Do you know that you are using version 20 of the support library? Have you tried using a newer version? The latest is 23.1.0.

Comment: Changing from 20.+ to 23.1 has no effect

Comment: You are applying the Android plugin in your build.gradle, correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can manually search the android support library jar in the android sdk directory and then copy it to a directory included in your projects library path. I believe the jar should be somewhere  in the \extras\android\support directory.

Note: I must do that when developing android apps with netbeans + android plugin. Not sure if android studio is supposed to pick the support library automatically from the sdk folder.

Comment: Hi what do you mean by "a directory in my project's library path"? I found it and added it as a library in libs, but that causes untold gradle errors

Comment: Oh, I meant exactly that: add it as a library in libs. I suppose some extra step is missing. I found the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library   they managed to add a .jar manually, perhaps you can foollow the steps of the first answer.